# PROCESS_SHARED/ROBUST pthread_mutex_t dealocks instead of returning EOWNERDEAD

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, mutex, deadlock

In my case, I need some lock in shm so I used pthread_mutex_t object.

Each pthread_mutex_t will be initialized as below so it can be shared between processes and is able to retore if the process exits while holding it.

```
pthread_mutexattr_t attr;                                                                                                                                                                            
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);                                                                                                                                                                       
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);                                                                                                                                         
pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST);                                                                                                                                            
pthread_mutex_init(&m_lock, &attr);
```

I tried to trigger the pthread_mutex_lock returns EOWNERDEAD case through steps below:

1. Start one process and create one pthread_mutex_t in shm as described above;
2. pthread_mutex_lock the lock in shm explicitly and exit the process;
3. Start another process, get the lock in shm and try to lock it again with pthread_mutex_lock;

The issue is that I observed in step 3 deadlock, i.e. the pthread_mutex_lock never returns.

But according to [pthread mutex document](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html#:%7E:text=is%20not%20recoverable.-,%5BEOWNERDEAD%5D,is%20up%20to%20the%20new%20owner%20to%20make%20the%20state%20consistent.,-The%20pthread_mutex_lock()%20function), in this case the pthread_mutex_lock should return EOWNERDEAD, indicating the holding process exitted while holding the process.

Test env is :

1. 5.15.0-1033-aws Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
2. g++ --version
   g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

Comment: You did not reinitialize the mutex in step 3, right?

Comment: @JeffGarrett  yes, the lock in shm only gets initialzied when constructed in step 1.. In step 3, I only got the lock pointer from shm and use it .

Comment: We will want a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Wild guess: the issue is primarily to do with the shared memory, not the mutex itself.

Comment: FWIW, I just whipped up my own robust mutex demo (on CentOS Stream 8), and inconsistent mutex detection and recovery worked as advertised.

Comment: One possible shared-memory issue would be that you have stored a pointer to the mutex there, rather than the mutex itself.  Pointers are not valid across unrelated processes, so it pretty much never makes sense to put them in shared memory.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the information ,but this should not be a problem since I store a offset pointer in shm to make sure the pointer is the same physical memory across multiple start.

Comment: @FaceBro, adding a bounty to this question will get it more attention, but does not make it any more *answerable*.  Glibc's robust mutexes work as documented.  We cannot tell you why your particular program behaves differently than you expect without examining its details.  As I wrote before, we need a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using pthread_mutex_consistent after acquiring the lock with EOWNERDEAD return value? This function is used to mark the state protected by the robust mutex as consistent again

Comment: @user1874594 The issue is the second lock never returns and seems a dead lock.

Comment: One thing you could try is to use `pthread_mutex_trylock `instead of pthread_mutex_lock to see if it returns a different error code. You could also try to reproduce the issue with a minimal example and see if the behavior persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, I found the robust mutex in shm is only marked as inconsistent when holding process/thread exits `abnormally`.

When the process exits normally through exit(0) or main function returns successfully, the lock in shm is in consistent locked status, hence causes the next lock operation blocks forever.